# Unity UI Resume Game button is unclickable

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i have been trying to create a pause menu for my project, however the resume button is un-clickable (the same i believe for another button on this menu). The event system does not show anything when hovering over this button or attempting to click it.
[Screenshot of Event System not showing button object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wto45.jpg)
The button itself is set to interact-able and has the button's image as it's target graphic. The canvas it is also placed on also has the Graphic Ray-caster component attached. I also do not believe that there is any UI object covering the button preventing it from being clicked.[Screenshot of Pause Menu UI as seen from scene view to show no blocking objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAmR6.png) I am making use of the first person character controller starter asset by unity as well as the new input system.

I am unsure as to what could be causing this, I have also tried locking the cursor of the starter asset inputs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the panel prevent the mouse, try disable graphic raycaster in the panel

Comment: The panel doesn't have a graphic raycaster on it. The canvas does which the menu is attached to, did you mean this?

Comment: yeah, its it :))))